# SQL: Filter rows with max value

Tags: sql, sqlite, greatest-n-per-group

This is my table structure:

```
File    |   Version     |   Function
1       |   1           |   1
1       |   2           |   1
1       |   3           |   1
1       |   2           |   2

2       |   1           |   4
3       |   2           |   5
```

I need it to return these rows only

```
1       |   3           |   1
2       |   1           |   4
3       |   2           |   5
```

Meaning I only want the functions that have the most recent version for each file.

I do not want the result below, i.e unique function ids that are not the most recent version

```
1       |   3           |   1
1       |   2           |   2
...
```

I've looked at [How can I SELECT rows with MAX(Column value), DISTINCT by another column in SQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612231/how-can-i-select-rows-with-maxcolumn-value-distinct-by-another-column-in-sql), but that returns the most recent unique function ids.

The query needs to be sqlite3 compatible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An efficient way to do this is often to use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from table t
where not exists (select 1
                  from table t2
                  where t2.file = t.file and t2.Version > t.version
                 );
```

This query can take advantage of an index on `table(file, version)`.

This rephrases the query to be:  "Get me all rows from the table where the corresponding file has no larger version."

Comment: Worked prefectly, thank you. Could you possibly look at my next question since you solved 1/4 of that one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24719716/sql-complex-sum-from-multiple-tables

Answer (score 2):

In SQLite 3.7.11 or later, when you use MAX, the other values are guaranteed to come from the row with the largest value:

```
SELECT File,
       MAX(Version) AS Version,
       Function
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY File
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that this will return multiple rows per file if the overall latest version for a file exists for different functions. i.e. if your example above had an additional row `(1,3,2)` this would return 2 rows for file `1`.

```
select
    t1.file,
    t1.version,
    t1.function
from 
    mytable t1
join (
    select 
        t2.file,
        max(t2.version) max_version        
    from  mytable t2
    group by t2.file
) t3 join t1.file = t3.file and t1.version = t3.max_version
```