# SQLite Join - query most recent posts by each user

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

In a sqlite database i have a "Users" table as follows

Users:

```
| user_id  | user                       
| 1        | John               
| 2        | Peter
```

a "Posts" table as follows:

```
| post_id | user_id     | text
| 10      | 1           | blah blah blah
| 11      | 1           | blah blah blah
| 12      | 2           | blah blah blah
```

I'm using this code to join two tables:

```
SELECT * FROM Users JOIN Posts USING ( user_id )
```

Now i have a list of all posts by different users as follows:

```
| user_id  | user         | post_id   | text           
| 1        | John         | 10        | blah blah blah
| 1        | John         | 11        | blah blah blah
| 2        | Peter        | 12        | blah blah blah
```

Assuming that the post with bigger post_id is posted more recently.
Now i want a list of most recent posts by each users (row #2 and #3 in this case).
How can i do this?
I'm thinking of deleting all rows (for each users) , except the rows which has biggest post_id (most recent), is this a good solution? how should i query it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Filter rows with max value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24708109/sql-filter-rows-with-max-value)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an inner query that gets you the latest post for each user, then that table will act as a filter when joined with the other two.

```
select  *
from    users u
join    (
            select  user_id, max(post_id) post_id
            from    Posts
            group by user_id
        ) r
on      u.user_id = r.user_id
join    posts p
on      r.post_id = p.post_id and
        r.user_id = p.user_id
```

Comment: This gives me 3 duplicate columns! but thanks , i changed it a bit and it worked fine. i removed 3 last lines and changed "on u.user_id ..." to "using (id)"

Answer (score 2):

In SQLite (but not in any other DB), when using GROUP BY, you can use max() or min() to select which row to return in a group:

```
SELECT user_id,
       user,
       max(post_id) AS post_id,
       text
FROM Users
JOIN Posts USING ( user_id )
GROUP BY user_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the query a little bit. you have to write the query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM Users Join Posts Using(user_id) order by post_id desc;
```

Comment: But i want to delete duplicate rows , this will only change order of rows

Comment: change the query:
    Select distinct  U.user_id,U.user,P.post-id,P.text from Users U,Posts P where U.user_id=P.user_id order by post_id desc;